# Specify the number of decimal digits on the explicit generator of a sequence in Raku

Tags: sequence, raku, significant-digits, rational-number

I've written a simple code:

```perl
sub euler-ex ($x) of Seq {
   1, { $x**++$ / [×] 1 .. ++$ } ... Inf }
say " 5: " ~ euler-ex(5)[^20]  ~ " = " ~ [+](euler-ex(5)[^20]);
```

The output:

```
5: 1 5 12.5 20.833333 26.041667 26.041667 21.701389 15.500992 9.68812 5.382289 2.6911445 1.22324748 0.50968645 0.19603325 0.07001187499 0.023337291662 0.0072929036444 0.00214497166011 0.000595825461143 0.000156796173985 = 148.41310786833832
```

How to specify the number of digits on that output, i.e. on the decimals coming out of the explicit generator of the sequence?

Comment: Hi @Lars. If neither of the answers are acceptable, but you have a solution (perhaps building on one or both of them), please consider writing an answer with that solution, and then accepting your own answer to helpfully guide future readers, and/or, if one or both answers are already acceptable, accept one, or, if you don't yet know of an acceptable solution, add a comment below whichever is closer, or under both of them, about what's missing. Thanks!

Comment: @raiph Thank you for pointing it out.  I took the first answer as accepted answer but I just happened to forget to mark it as such :(. Actually, I knew  the `fmt` method  2 years ago while I was learning and frequently using Raku but after a long pause I had completely forgot it. So, that answer has been a nice reminder too :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the last line to

```
say " 5: " ~ euler-ex(5)[^20].fmt("%0.10f")  ~ "=" ~ [+](euler-ex(5)[^20]).fmt("%0.10f");
```

and get output like

```
 5: 1.0000000000 5.0000000000 12.5000000000 20.8333333333 26.0416666667 26.0416666667 21.7013888889 15.5009920635 9.6881200397 5.3822889109 2.6911444555 1.2232474798 0.5096864499 0.1960332500 0.0700118750 0.0233372917 0.0072929036 0.0021449717 0.0005958255 0.0001567962=148.4131078683
```

You might be interested to know that this sequence is generating `Rat`s, so you could get the exact value if you want. You can see the "raw" values with

```
dd euler-ex(5)[^20];

(1, 5.0, 12.5, <125/6>, <625/24>, <625/24>, <3125/144>, <15625/1008>, <78125/8064>, <390625/72576>, <390625/145152>, <1953125/1596672>, <9765625/19160064>, <48828125/249080832>, <244140625/3487131648>, <244140625/10461394944>, <1220703125/167382319104>, <6103515625/2845499424768>, <30517578125/51218989645824>, <152587890625/973160803270656>)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked out when I added `fmt("%0.2f")` , it printed out neat 2 digit decimals. Thank you for the hint on showing the raw values, too.

Answer (score 5):

You can [`round`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/round) a number to wanted scale:

```raku
>>> 12.8471 .round(0.01)
12.85
```

12.8471 is rounded to the nearest multiple of 0.01; effectively, 2 decimal places.

You have a sequence of numbers, so [`map`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/map) is there:

```raku
>>> (1, * +  ... *) .head(5)
(1 3.718281828459045 6.43656365691809 9.154845485377136 11.87312731383618)

>>> (1, * +  ... *) .map(*.round(0.01)) .head(5)
(1 3.72 6.44 9.15 11.87)
```

So for, e.g., 2 decimal points, need 0.01 == 10 ** -2; then we can argumentize this to the function:

```raku
sub euler-ex($x, Int :$digits) of Seq {
   my $seq := 1, { $x ** ++$ / [×] 1 .. ++$ } ... Inf;
   $digits
       ?? $seq.map(*.round(10 ** -$digits))
       !! $seq
}

>>> euler-ex(5).head(6)
(1 5 12.5 20.833333 26.041667 26.041667)

>>> euler-ex(5, :3digits).head(6)
(1 5 12.5 20.833 26.042 26.042)
```

If `$digits` is supplied (and nonzero...), the sequence will be returned back with its computed values rounded to that many decimal places. Otherwise, as is.

---

Noting that `round` gives back a numeric value (e.g., Rational above), and `12.3. round(0.01)` would give `12.3` not `12.30`, i.e., trailing zeros are not put. If that is wanted, `.fmt` as the other answer (but in `map`; or `sprintf`) is possible (noting that they give strings).